# iOS 5 - Where should NSURLConnection go for an app with multiple views?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I am writing an app that has various views; but all of them basically need an access to a connection so they can retrieve data from a server.

Now I was kinda lost about where should I put the code to initialize the connection and retrieve the data.

IF i put it in the viewDidLoad; the connection will be created and the data retrieved every time that the user switch view (I have a tab bar to switch between views); and this is not hat I want (for obvious reasons, the data should be retrieved only if the user tap on the refresh button, and the connection should not be created every time that the view switch).

Where should I put the method that creates the connection and retrieve the data, so I can access this data from anywhere in the app (more specifically the other views of the app; each view show different parts of the data downloaded from the server) and avoid to overload the user and shrink the battery life with continuous connections and data retrieval?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> (for obvious reasons, the data should be retrieved only if the user
>   tap on the refresh button, and the connection should not be created
>   every time that the view switch).

If you only want to sync the data in response to the user tapping a button, then create a method

```
- (IBAction)syncData;
```

and in Interface builder connect the touchUpInside event of the button to the syncData method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eric. But what about the connection? Do i create, instantiate and close the connection inside the method? Should't I keep the connection around instead of creating it every time that I push the button?